# Gamma Regression as the Last Layer of the Neural Network

Tags: generalized-linear-model, python, gamma-distribution, tensorflow

My current task involves predicting data that follows a Gamma distribution. To avoid confusion of notations, in the following discussion, the p.d.f will be $$\mathbb{P}(y|\alpha, \beta)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}y^{\alpha - 1}\exp(-\beta y)$$ and by taking $\eta = -\beta, b(y) = \frac{y^{\alpha - 1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}, a(\eta) = -\alpha \log(-\eta)$, the activation will be $$h_\theta(x) = -\frac{\alpha}{\theta^T x}$$ and the negative log-likelihood loss will be $$l(\theta) = \alpha \log h_\theta (x) + \frac{\alpha y}{h_\theta(x)}+\log \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\alpha^\alpha y^{\alpha - 1}}$$

Currently, I am using trivial activation and the traditional squared error loss in the last layer, though knowing that the distribution is by no means normal. And the model is indeed not performing optimally at the samples with the lower value, roughly around the maximum of the p.d.f. Therefore I assume that using gamma regression will help reduce the error.

If I apply `ReLu` activation in the last but one layer, therefore the input of the last layer $x$ is guaranteed to be positive (for all entries), therefore to prevent "explosion" caused by the $\theta^T x\geq 0$, $\theta$ has better be negative at all times. How do I enforce these constraints (for initialization and updates) in practice (by implementing the activation and loss function in TensorFlow, for example)? Or is there any package that provides such layers? (`tfp` seems to be supporting the GLM models but is there a way to combine them into a deep learning model?)

Comment: The inverse of the canonical link function seems to be for generalized linear models what the role of the activation function is for neural networks. At least this is the case for logistic regression with a logit link compared to classification NNs with a logistic (=sigmoid) activation. 

Then the 'inverse' f(x) = -1/x would be the "right" activation function. Because of stability, in practice people seem to prefer to approximate this with a log/exp, so maybe consider a exp(-x) activation?